# boost serialization throws exception for large objects

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I'm trying to serialize objects that are over 50mb in size --- in particular, these objects contain very large arrays of floats (50+ million).  The serialization function seems to fail, and throw an exception (e=735).

Any ideas as to why this might happen and how to possibly solve the issue?

Note: I have no problem serializing objects whose size is an order of magnitude smaller (5 million floats or less).

Comment: Can you post either a stack trace of the exception being throw or post a self-contained, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: this could depend a lot of your code, and you didn't show any.

Comment: DO you know if there are any limitations on the size of data one can serialize with boost?

Comment: There are all kinds of limits due to the format used, file size limits, memory limits, and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, boost serialization is not a good fit for all possible data... That's why people have to roll up their own serialization libs sometimes